# Spring Security ACL extensions to support delegations

Tags: spring, security, permissions, delegates, acl

I am working on a Grails project that protects resources using Spring Security ACL plugin.
This application also allows resource owners to delegate permissions  to other users and those users can further delegate their permissions to other users in viral fashion.

This works fine with standard Spring ACL API, but now I have new requirements:

1. Track who granted/delegated the given permission [User should be able to
   see his/her permissions on a given resource as well as all other users
   permissions that he/she delegated for that resource].
2. Control viral delegate by grantee by setting a flag to indicate if
   this permission can be further delegatable.

I am planing to support those requirements by adding two additional fields [ 1. grantee (SID) , 2. isDelegatable ] to ACL_ENTRY table.
I wonder if it will impact any of the Spring ACL core functionality. How can I access those fields using standard Spring ACL API? Can I cast to custom Permission object and access those extended fields?

We are also planing to support time based expirable Permissions which are only applicable during given start and end time frame. where should I add this validation logic so that hasPermission() method call consider the time validity of the granted Permission?
Please advice.